# Linked List - Reverse a Linked List in groups of K

Tags: java

I was following [this Java solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-list-in-groups-of-given-size/) to understand the given problem

I got most of it, the reversal logic, the recursion part but under the main method, I don't get why we are assigning the head value to the value returned by the reverse method.

```
llist.head = llist.reverse(llist.head, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In llist.reverse(llist.head, 3);  it will reverse the head list with specified length(3) and assigning back to  llist.head.

1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->NULL, K = 3

After first iteration

**3->2->1**->4->5->6->7->8->NULL - it reverse the first 3 elements and in second iteration

3->2->1->**6->5->4**->7->8->NULL 
and in last iteration
3->2->1->6->5->4->8->7->NULL

finally llist.head holds the 3->2->1->6->5->4->8->7->NULL

Comment: Doesn't head hold only the first value of the list..? Your comment implies the list.head holds the whole list at the end or am I getting you wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: It indeed just holds the one node at the beginning. But that has a pointer to the next, which has a pointer to the next, ...